# When soft keyboard appear Scroll not working I have tried lot of things but nothing work?

Tags: android, android-layout

Fragment Layout in which scroll is not working
I have tried my thing like 
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
but nothing work......

## i have checked with all mode of windowsoftinput modes but nothing work for me

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/white">


        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                android:id="@+id/sign_up_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/title_field_hint"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                app:floatingLabel="highlight" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/titles_spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </FrameLayout>


        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_fname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/first_name_field_hint"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:floatingLabel="highlight"/>


        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_lname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/last_name_field_hint"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:floatingLabel="highlight"/>


        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/email_field_hint"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:floatingLabel="highlight"/>

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_passwrd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/password_filed_hint"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:floatingLabel="highlight"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sign_up"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/red_btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/sign_up"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_progress"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</FrameLayout>
```

**App Theme

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="MainTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAppCompatDialogTheme" parent="MainTheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateAlwaysHidden</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: where do you have ScrollView defined?

Comment: try to use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in your manifest activity declaration

Comment: where is scroll view in xml.